# How to programmatically move a tab to another window in a firefox Addon-SDK extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

While it looks like you can change the *order* of a tab within a window by updating the tab `.index` property, it doesn't look like the [tabs api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) directly supports the move of a tab to another window.

Am I missing something? Is there a viable workaround?

Comment: Awesome question Hans!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible through the low level module `window/utils`. The example below duplicates the active tab across every open window

```js
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow, windows: getWindows } = require("sdk/window/utils");

const { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

var button = ActionButton({
  id: "duplicatetab-button",
  label: "Duplicate tab",
  icon: "data:image/png;base64,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",
  onClick: function() {
    var xulwindows = getWindows("navigator:browser");
    var xulactivewindow = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    var xulactivetab = xulactivewindow.gBrowser.selectedTab;

    xulwindows.forEach(function(win){
      if(win === xulactivewindow)
        return;
      var duplicatedtab = win.gBrowser.duplicateTab(xulactivetab);
      win.gBrowser.moveTabTo(duplicatedtab, 0); // the second argument is the index
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Is duplicating the real way to move? If you're playing a video in a tab and duplicate the tab then its no longer playing the video if you duplicate it.

Comment: It duplicates the **tab** state, that doesn't include the complete content window state.

Comment: Hey paa man we should be doing docshell swapping right? That wuld be better as it preserves stuff. do you know how to docShell swap? im trying to learn. apparently this is how firefox moves a tab to a new window.

Comment: @Noitidart `duplicateTab` is the way Firefox does it.

Answer (score 2):

@paa's solution is nice but it doesn't move a tab. His is duplicating the tab. So flash movies will not retain their position etc. And its not a move its a duplicatio, like he explained.

I did a lot of research was real fun. The way they move tabs in Firefox is via docShell swapping. This will accomplish what you want. It's written for bootstrap though so needs touch up for addon sdk.

Pass second argument as string of `tabbed` or `non-tabbed` if you want to move it to a new window. Else pass second argument an existing window and it will be moved there. can copy paste and run this code from sratchpad.

this uses the `gBrowser.swapBrowsersAndCloseOther` function

```
function moveTabToWin(aTab, tDOMWin) {
  //tDOMWin means target DOMWindow means the window you want the tab in
  //if tDOMWin == 'tabbed' or == 'non-tabbed' it opens in a new window
  //if aTopContWin is the last in its window, then its window is closed
  if (tDOMWin == 'tabbed' || tDOMWin == 'non-tabbed') {
    var sa = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-array;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsArray);
    var wuri = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsString);
    wuri.data = 'about:blank';
    sa.AppendElement(wuri);
    let features = "chrome,dialog=no";
    if (tDOMWin == 'tabbed') {
      features += ',all';
    }
    var sDOMWin = aTab.ownerGlobal; //source DOMWindow
    if (PrivateBrowsingUtils.permanentPrivateBrowsing || PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate(sDOMWin)) {
       features += ",private";
    } else {
       features += ",non-private";
    }
    var XULWindow = Services.ww.openWindow(null, 'chrome://browser/content/browser.xul', null, features, sa);
    XULWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var DOMWindow = XULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
      DOMWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.stop(Ci.nsIWebNavigation.STOP_ALL);
      DOMWindow.gBrowser.swapBrowsersAndCloseOther(DOMWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab, aTab);
      //DOMWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab = newTab;
    }, false);
  } else if (tDOMWin) {
    //existing dom window
    var newTab = tDOMWin.gBrowser.addTab('about:blank');
    newTab.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.stop(Ci.nsIWebNavigation.STOP_ALL);
    tDOMWin.gBrowser.swapBrowsersAndCloseOther(newTab, aTab);
    tDOMWin.gBrowser.selectedTab = newTab;
  }
}

moveTabToWin(gBrowser.selectedTab, 'tabbed');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'v got inspired by @Noitidart's answer and came up with my solution.

I'm adding `setWindow(window, index)` method to `Tab`'s prototype, so that any SDK tab can be moved to another window from anywhere in the addon with a simple call like this:

```
browserWindows[0].activeTab.setWindow(browserWindows.activeWindow, 0);
```

This will move active tab of window 0 to the beginning of active window.

And here is the method:

**Update:**

I've put together a module to do exactly this: [jetpack-tab-setwindow](https://github.com/duzun/jetpack-tab-setwindow)

---

**Old solution** (breaks in FF43)

```
var Tab = require("sdk/tabs/tab").Tab;

Tab.prototype.setWindow = function (window, index) {
    var tab = this;
    var oldWindow = tab.window;
    if ( oldWindow !== window ) {
        // We have to use lower-level API here
        var Ci      = require('chrome').Ci;
        var viewFor = require("sdk/view/core").viewFor;

        var aTab = viewFor(tab);
        var aWin = viewFor(window);
        var gBrowser = aWin.gBrowser;

        // Get tab properties
        var isSelected = oldWindow.activeTab == tab;
        var isPinned   = aTab.pinned;

        // Log for debugging:
        var tabId = tab.id;
        console.log('setWindow', {index, isSelected, isPinned, tab, tabId});

        // Create a placeholder-tab on destination windows
        var newTab = gBrowser.addTab('about:newtab');
        newTab.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.stop(Ci.nsIWebNavigation.STOP_ALL); // we don't need this tab anyways

        // If index specified, move placeholder-tab to desired index
        if ( index != undefined ) {
            var length = gBrowser.tabContainer.childElementCount;
            if ( index < 0 ) index = length - index;
            if( 0 <= index && index < length ) {
                gBrowser.moveTabTo(newTab, index);
            }
        }
        // Copy tab properties to placeholder-tab
        if ( isPinned ) {
            gBrowser.pinTab(newTab);
        }

        // For some reason this doesn't seem to work :-(
        if ( isSelected ) {
            gBrowser.selectedTab = newTab;
        }

        // Swap tabs and remove placeholder-tab
        gBrowser.swapBrowsersAndCloseOther(newTab, aTab);
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow very nice @Duzun! Thanks for sharing! A user asked how to do it in the SDK and your solution fits him much better then mine - https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/tear-off-tab-with-sdk/7085/2

Comment: Thank you for original solution @Noitidart!

My solution is missing something, as of FF 43-44 I get strange error without any details (stack, file, description - nothing).
I guess it is because I'm accessing the new tab to early or something... Sometimes I end up with a blank window (no tabs) that doesn't close.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that symptom, hopefully someone can address that. :)

Comment: I see @kousu found a better solution for moving a tab to a new window at https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/tear-off-tab-with-sdk/7085/9 using `replaceTabWithWindow()`. I can't login there to comment, something is broken in the authorization system :-(

His solution doesn't seem to work for moveing to an existing window, but I believe there should be a better solution then I used in `setWindow()` for the generic problem of movein tabs to different windows.

Comment: I'll share this comment with him. If you can sign up and join in when the system is working that would be awesome. :)

Comment: Hey Duzun message from @kousu to you :) ---  I had the exactly same trouble until I turned off all my ad blockers---for some reason the login system didn't list Persona, and I just had to allow everything globally. Once I got the cookie I was able to turn things back on, though. I believe that tracing out the internal `return window.openDialog(getBrowserURL(), "_blank", options, aTab);` will tell us how to setWindow() as well. https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/tear-off-tab-with-sdk/7085/13?u=noitidart